# child browser in sencha

Tags: facebook, twitter, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

In my Jquery mobile application i used child browser for Facebook and twitter authentication and i asked user to login at facebook(in childbrowser) and in childbrowser onlocation change i am executing a function, there i am getting facebook username to register in my database.

Now i am trying to do this in sencha without child browser.

i asked this question before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081277/alternative-for-child-browser-in-sencha-mobile-application)), but i did't get any answer or even reply.

**Is there any way i can do this without child browser or i must use child browser?**

Comment: why i did't get single reply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used window.open() for authentication... i use php(yii) backend and i let yii oAuth service take care of authentication